# Load QQuickView from QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

Is there some way to load `QQuickView`  with string data?
As I know there is only `void QQuickView::setSource(const QUrl & url)`.

I can load a `QQmlComponent` with string data but now how can I assign this component to `QQuickView`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the engine of `QQuickView` when creating a `QQmlComponent` :

```
QQmlComponent component(view->engine(), QUrl("path/to/file.qml"));
```

Comment: As I said, I need to load data from string, not file. So I write folowing code: 
`QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
QQmlComponent *component = new QQmlComponent(view->engine());
component->setData(data,QUrl());
view->show();`
And it not works. It open a window but this window is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I recently confronted this problem and solved using the `QQuickWindow::contentItem()` like this.

```
...
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    QQmlComponent com(view.engine());  
    com.setData(QByteArrayLiteral("... QML source ..."), QUrl())

    QQuickItem *root = qobject_cast<QQuickItem *>(com.create());
    root->setParentItem(view.contentItem());
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```